# PPT 2013 Template Issue

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, templates, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I have formed a new template in PPT 2013.  It is stored in the correct (?) folder ie: user\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Template\

When I open a new presentation my template does open OK (I named it Blank) but only the first slide is with the template - all the others are the "old" MS blank template.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Isn't `Blank` something like default template name? If you name the template `Blank2015`, it the problem still there?

Comment: First:  are you trying to create a new default template so that PPT automatically starts new blank presentations using your template?  Next:  by "open a new presentation" and "template does open", what exactly do you mean?  It may help if you describe the exact steps you followed rather than (easily misinterpreted) descriptions.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Yes I would like to have a template for all the slides in one presentation.  I tried setting up custom template and failed.  i then set up a default, named blank which successfully opens any new presentation, however only the first slide in that presentation is my template.  When I use add a slide it just generates a blank slide, ie does not include the elements which successfully appeared on the initial slide.

Comment: @ miroxlav  Thank you for the response.  I changed to blank2015, PPT opened a blank slide and told me it couldn't find Blank.potx.  I renamed it blank.potx and it did open, but only the first slide was in the format of the template I designed

Comment: Perhaps you can upload your POTX file somewhere so I can check it for you.  Also when replying, please use `@username` instead of `@ username` because [se] sends notification only if there is no space character.

Comment: @miroxlav Thank you - I'd be grateful.  I am not sure if I can paste here, but I'll try:

Comment: Thank you miroxlav, I'd appreciate that:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/m3l227vrxtvuoam/Blank.potx?dl=0